# Configure maven-war-plugin to include project classes in root of WAR

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

Is it possible to configure the maven-war-plugin so that it adds the project's classes into the root of the WAR as well as into WEB-INF/classes?

An overlay requires that the classes be a dependency so that doesn't seem like it will work for classes within the same project.

At the moment I am using the antrun-plugin to copy the classes  over during pre-package, but it feels a little hacky. Is there a cleaner solution? If so what?

Comment: Why do you need the classed in the root of the WAR ?What's the intention behind? What would you like to achieve ?

Comment: I want to make a runnable WAR. I have investigated many solutions and the only one that supports all my requirements is http://qdolan.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/embedded-jar-classloader-in-under-100.html. But it still leaves the problem that an executable archive looks for its class in the root of the archive (manifest classpath is ignored)